# display date only once [elegant way]

Tags: mysql

How do I display the date *only once* using the inbuilt [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

If I do, `select curdate() from abc.xyz;` it would return something like this,

```
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
|    ...     |
| 2013-07-23 |
| 2013-07-23 |
| 2013-07-23 |
| 2013-07-23 |
|    ...     |
+------------+
```

with number of rows equal to number of tuples in the table.

In order for it to return me this,

```
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2013-07-23 |
+------------+
```

I do, `select curdate() from abc.xyz LIMIT 1` or

`select DISTINCT curdate() from abc.xyz`

This gives me my expected output but it doesn't seem really sensible to me to use a random database and its table just for accessing the name. *What is the proper way of doing this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `FROM` clause at all.

The query in all it's glory:

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

And, [here's a fiddle with no tables at all](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3882) to demonstrate.

Comment: Actually I was working on Hadoop Hive and it was too slow so I assumed mysql will be nice to practice my query since my tables are same in both. I shot myself  in the foot, Hive gives error for `select curdate()` and I assumed the same for mysql. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Yeah, some engines will allow this, others require a table/FROM clause. Some engines also have a built-in table or pseudotable for this - in Firebird you can use `RDB$DATABASE` and Oracle I believe is `DUAL`. Worst case scenario, you can create a table that has just one row in it, write triggers to keep it that way, and then you can just select against that table.